# Bootstrap import interfereing with <figure> placement

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Take the following codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Xgqjyq

```css
h2 { 
 color: #111; 
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
 font-size: 20px; 
 font-weight: bold; 
 text-align: center; 
}

.content {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: .75em;
}

.image-cropper {
    width: 20%;
    height: 5%;
    position: relative;
    border: 0px solid white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 500px;
    overflow:hidden;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.info {
 color: black;
}


.interest {
 width:4em; 
 height:4em;
 padding-bottom: .2em; 
}

figure {
    display: inline-block;
 width: 8em;
}

figcaption {
 font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; 
 font-size: 17px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    header
     </a>
   </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
   <div>
     <h2>title</h2>
     <figure>
      <img class="interest" src="" alt="pic"/>
      <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
     </figure>
     <figure>
      <img class="interest" src="" alt="pic"/> 
      <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
     </figure>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Both of the figures are left aligned on their own line. However, if you remove the bootstrap style link at the top of the HTML, they become centered on one line like I want them.

But I need bootstrap for the header formatting.

Is there any way to fix this? I tried downloading a custom Bootstrap with just the nav elements, but that didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add in CSS:

```
figure{
float:left;
}
```

Enjoy !